# Is this design sufficient for a small library management system?

Tags: database-design, oracle11g, relational-database, relationship, database-normalization

**DB backend:** Oracle Xe (Project requirement)

**UI Frontend:** Wpf w/C#

---

I'm designing a database design for the software project I plan to undertake, starting with the logical design of the database.

The features of the library management system are simple and the focus is limited:

A table containing rows of individual book entries and their data/meta-data.

A student table to register accounts with overdue balances from late returns (derived data: 7 days past the borrow date)

And an Orders table that chiefly interacts with the C# program.

Other features: Search by ISBN, Insert book entries, Quantity Management

---

Does the following logical design reflect my intentions?

[image: Design]

- What sort of deletion rules should I implement per table?
- Should I be breaking certain tables down into more relations? Tables
  I might require?
- Does the order of the functions included in the image make sense
  given my intentions?

It's quite a simple design really, I just want to confirm any design decisions before moving forward with the actual programming.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. (Nb--A manual for a design tool, api or language to record designs is not a manual/tutorial on design.) PS See [ask]. Please ask one question per post. Ask a specific question about a specific part of your design. Preferably the first thing you are not sure about. Relate the issues to the textbook.